# Speech API micClient versus dataClient using raw microphone data

Tags: android, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the MCS Speech API to recognize speech using the microphone on an Android smartphone.

I have examples running for both the micClient and the dataClient.

Both examples convert speech to text, but when I use the micClient the speech to text conversion performance is much better than when I use the dataClient.

With the dataClient I am reading voice data from the microphone, PCM format, 16 bit, 16,000 samples per second, mono. The physical Android phone I'm using is the same for both examples.

I am not sure why the speech to text performance using the micClient is so much better than when using the dataClient.

I am wondering is there some kind of pre-processing done on the voice data when using the micClient, maybe filtering or noise suppression?

Thanks,
Barry.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Turns out when using raw data from the microphone with the dataClient I was missing buffers of audio data coming from the microphone due to processing time in other sections of the code.

I rearranged the code a little bit and now works as expected.

Thanks,
Gary.